# Xamarin UI Tests get info about device and app version

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, uitest

I have a question. Can I get in Xamarin UI Test information about device and app?
I need information like this (ios+android):

- System version.
- device id
- app version

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing out of the box that gives you this. Instead a good way to do it using a backdoor.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/

This is essentially a method you expose on your app, and you can call this using `IApp.Invoke()`, giving it the name of your method. These methods can take a string parameter and return a string. Inside this backdoor method you can get whatever details you want and return them.

We use this at work to get device info such as if it is a phone or tablet, the orientation that it's running in (so we can do custom test steps on landscape vs portrait). It's a very useful trick.